# What is exactly "op-ed"?

Tags: word-usage, usage, definition

Let me thank you in advance.

I am writing a blog for my business purpose and hit upon a word **["op-ed".](http://news.yahoo.com/scientist-takes-first-ever-photo-rare-bird-then-201207749.html)**

From the article,

> The incident led University of Colorado ecology professor Marc Bekoff to write in **an op-ed** for the Huffington Post: “Killing ‘in the name of conservation’ or ‘in the name of education’ or ‘in the name of whatever’ simply needs to stop. It is wrong and sets a horrific precedent for future research and for children.”

When I looked up to dictionaries, all the explanations are "Opposite to editorials".

So, am I correct to understand whereas "editorials" are the articles or sentences you can name, but the dictionaries also say, it is **not** an "open letters" to the editors ( = newspapers ).

Is it correct if I assume this "op-ed" thing is kind of a post from anybody unrelated with the newspaper company with the criticisim or that kind of sort  to the newspapers? ( so that they can "be fair"? ).

Let me thank you in advance again. Sincerely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most newspapers have a section where, instead of reporting on the news,  editors, journalists, civic leaders or other experts publish their personal interpretations (or *opinions*) about current events. Such articles might be called an *opinion piece,* or an *editorial*.

Sometimes, this section of the newspaper is entitled Editorials, and sometimes Opinions.

An *op-ed* piece is simply a newspaper article published in this section of the newspaper.

[image: Opinion section of newspaper]

<sup>Insofar as I know, the term *op-ed* is merely a shortened form of *Opinion-Editorial*.</sup>

In the sentence you originally found, Marc Bekoff was the author of the op-ed piece, and it was published by the Huffington Post. In my experience, it's not uncommon for newspapers to publish editorials written by professors.

Comment: Thank you Mr. J.R. It looks like I looked up something another....

Comment: NOAD says: `ORIGIN 1940s: shortening of op(posite the) ed(itorial page)`, so I guess I was wrong about "op" meaning "opinion."

Comment: Thank you...and it looks like I went into a deeper dungeon.......................

Answer (score 1):

The "editorial" are opinion pieces written by the publishers of the newspaper, and in old days were quite influential in shaping public opinion.

Op-Eds are opinion pieces written by someone not on the staff of the newspaper. The author of an op-ed is usually an expert or advocate of some kind, which distinguishes them from "letters to the editor" from the general public.

The name Op-Ed is "opposite the editorial," but originally referred to physical location, not necessarily opinion.  That is, an op-ed was on the page opposite the editorial, it might agree or disagree with the newspaper's editorial policy.